# I can't code sign my iOS application

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I've purchased the developer program earlier and I've installed the certificate into my keychain (both iPhone developer and iPhone distribution). When I'm going to deploy apps to real devices, Xcode gives me this error: 
 Code Sign error: There are no valid certificate/private key pairs in the default keychain. 
When I go to Organizer>Teams, there is an error and here is the message: 
Unable to code sign using identities in this team: no private keys available. 
And when I go to Provisioning Profiles, there is this error: Valid signing identity not found. 
I've tried downloading the certificates from the portal and move them to my keychain again, but I've seen that no keys are coming with these certificates. Where can I get the keys? And also, I didn't see the Software Signing certificate in my keychain either. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Exact same issue except that mine was working fine and all of a sudden stopped working and showed these errors. My certificate/provisioning profile have not expired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've resolved this problem by deleting everything related to signing of apps (so in Xcode, Keychain Access, and on developer.apple.com) and make new profiles following the wizard (called launch assistant) on [the homepage of the provisioning portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action).

Comment: Thanks @dragon112. I fixed this by your solution. Just clear all settings (including certifications, devices, provisions...) in personal provisioning portal, then follow the exact instructions of launch assistent, then everything should be fine!!

Comment: This didn't work for me. I cannot figure out how to get the public/private key pair back into the keychain, which is a step with the assistant.

Comment: @kakyo nobody tells you, but the private key is produced when you issue the certificate request, you can see it in Keychain's Keys section. After you generate the certificate using the cert request, you install the certificate and it will automatically pair with the private key, you can then export both in a single .p12 file (make sure you select BOTH keys before saving them).

Comment: @kakyo and by the way, make sure you check "Let me specify key pair information" when issuing the certificate request form Certificate Asssitant